# Where FilterChainProxy bean is created with name springSecurityFilterChain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, spring-security

I'm working with Spring Security framework and I need to ask a question.
Here is my configuration to invoke FilterChainProxy using DelegatingFilterProxy.

```xml
<filter> 
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping> 
       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>
</filter>
```

As far as I found out, DelegatingFilterProxy invoke Filter interface implementation by specifying its name.
So, where (in the code) and when FilterChainProxy bean created with name "springSecurityFilterChain"?
Thank you.

Comment: That is part of the Spring Security configuration. Depending on which version that is either in the java configuration part or the XML namespace handeling code.

Comment: This seems to be extract from "web.xml" .. then "servlet container" initializes [this particular "filter" class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.java)(with name springSecurityFilterChain) ..and maps it to "context root" (`/*`)

Answer (score 0):

just add a class for security

```
package com.packageName.security;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BlogAppSecurityConfig{


@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
return http.build();
}

}
```